# python, sum of value from several rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have hundreds of csv files like the follows:

[image]

What I want to do it to calculate the sum of each row for columns `A_*`and `B_*`, respectively.

For example for `file_1.csv`, I use the following code:

```
#for file_1.csv

import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('file_1.csv')
df["A_sum"]=df["A_1"]+df["A_2"]+df["A_3"]
df["B_sum"]=df["B_1"]+df["B_2"]
df.to_csv (r'output_file_1.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

Since I have to process hundreds of files like this, How should I modify the code so that it can automatically identify how many `A` column and `b` column in a csv file and calculate the sum?

For example, it can generate code for `file_3.csv` like this:

```
#for file_3.csv

import pandas as pd 
df = pd.read_csv('file_3.csv')
df["A_sum"]=df["A_1"]+df["A_2"]
df["B_sum"]=df["B_1"]+df["B_2"]
df.to_csv (r'output_file_3.csv', index = False, header=True)
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `filter`:

```
ret_df = pd.DataFrame()

ret_df['A_sum'] = df.filter(like='A_').sum(1)
ret_df['B_sum'] = df.filter(like='B_').sum(1)
```

Or use regex, and also a loop:

```
for type in ['A','B']:
    df[f'{type}_sum'] = df.filter(regex=f'^{type}_').sum(1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Both works well.  May I ask how to delete columns ```A_* ``` and ```B_*```, and only keep the ```A_sum``` and  ```B_sum```?

Comment: Thank you so much. How about if the title of the column is like this ```A_1_X```,  ```A_2_X``` ? And I want the title of new column like this ```A_X_sum```. Could you please add your answer after your previous one? Thanks.

Comment: @Lemor use `df.filter(regex='A_\d+_X')`

Comment: Could you please have a look at this issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64374751/python-sum-of-value-in-a-row-based-on-the-head-of-the-columns