# Sum value in a row based on the head of the columns

Tags: python, regex, dataframe

I have a dataset like this:
[image]

I want to calculate the sum of `apple_*_C`,`apple_*_Cr`, `apple_*_Cu` in each row, respectively, with the following code.

```
for test in ['apple']:
    df[f'{test}_C']=df.filter(regex=f'^{test}_\d_C').sum(1)
    df[f'{test}_C']=df.filter(regex=f'^{test}_\d_Cr').sum(1)
    df[f'{test}_C']=df.filter(regex=f'^{test}_\d_Cu').sum(1)
```

However,`df[f'{test}_C']=df.filter(regex=f'^{test}_\d_C').sum(1)` will calculate the sum of `apple_*_C` and`apple_*_Cr`, `apple_*_Cu` in a row, rather than only `apple_*_C`.
Please advise how should I modify it.

Comment: Use "$" to anchor to the end, similar to how "^" anchors to the start: `df.filter(regex=f'^{test}_\d_C$').sum(1)`

Comment: why do your right 3 time on the same result-column ?

Answer (score 1):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
    "Apple_1_C" : [1,2],
    "Apple_2_C" : [2,3],
    "Apple_3_C" : [3,4],
    "Apple_1_Cr" : [4,5],
    "Apple_1_Cr" : [5,6],
    "Apple_1_Cu" : [6,7],    
    "Apple_2_Cu" : [7,8],        
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

df
```

[image]

```
for i, test in enumerate(['Apple']):
    df[f'{test}_C_sum']=df.filter(regex=f'^{test}_\d_C$').sum(1)
    df[f'{test}_Cr_sum']=df.filter(regex=f'^{test}_\d_Cr').sum(1)
    df[f'{test}_Cu_sum']=df.filter(regex=f'^{test}_\d_Cu').sum(1)
df
```

[image]